# MySQL String to Date converting with varying strings?

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I need to convert dates of varying strings.  They come in 3 different ways.

**yyyy/mm/dd**

**mm/dd/yyyy**

or **blank** (can fill in some default)

What is a good way to handle this situation for an INSERT statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use STR_TO_DATE function in combination with COALESCE - something like:

```
set @strdate := '2014/05/10';
select COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(@strdate,'%m/%d/%Y'),STR_TO_DATE(@strdate,"%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Comment: Right. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19168/2 You need to put the format ending in "%Y" first in the `COALESCE()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL str_to_date() function. It requires one format and will return NULL if the data doesnt match the format. UseCoalesce with str_to_date with str_to_date in descending order of likelihood of the format.

Example if yyyy/mm/dd is more common than mm/dd/yyyy then use

`COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(your_date_here,'%Y/%m/%d'),STR_TO_DATE(@strdate,"%m/%d/%Y"))`

Edit: This is the same as Ondřej Šotek's answer but with a possible performance improvement

Comment: You need to use %Y instead of %y, your solution returns wrong year because it works with 2 digit year only.